# How to compute gradient with kernels' positive part?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I have a trained CNN detection network(yolo-tiny-v3) in keras+tensorflow and need to compute gradients of output and input image (For updating input image iteratively, not conv-kernels params).

But, I need to use positive part of conv-kernels to compute gradients not common gradients.
In forward propagation, original kernels are used to compute output. But in backward propagation, relu(conv-kernels) need to be used to compute gradients.

Is there some tensorflow operators could achieve this directly?(like gradient_override_map I have used).
Thank you very much.

Here is my code - gradients times activation maps. Capital L means list of python.

```
gradients = tf.gradients(yolo_outputs_masked_L, conv_layer_outputs)
grad_ams_L = []
for i_layer_num in range(len(conv_layer_outputs)):
    grad_am = conv_layer_outputs[i_layer_num] * gradients[i_layer_num]
    grad_ams_L.append(grad_am)
```